# Rails Rspec test session variable in decorator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, controller

I have a decorator that receives the application controller as a variable in order to access session variables. Something like:

```
navigation = NavigationDecorator(user_id, self)
```

Self being the ApplicationController.

Everything works fine, but now I have to test it and in Rspec I did

```
navigation = NavigationDecorator(user_id, ApplicationController.new)
```

During my tests I get:

```
ActionController::Metal#session delegated to @_request.session, but @_request is nil: #<ApplicationController:0x000000161363f0 @_routes=nil, @_action_has_layout=true, @_headers={"Content-Type"=>"text/html"}, @_status=200, @_request=nil, @_response=nil>
```

Updating:

I use it like this:

```
def initialize(user, controller)
    @controller = controller
    ...
end

def retrieve_user_id
    user_id = @controller.session[:temporary_id] if @controller.session[:temporary_id]
    super
end
```

Comment: Could you show the code of NavigationDecorator? How do you use ApplicationController in there?

Comment: Hello @SheinAlexey! I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd propose to stub controller in the test, because since you're writing unit test (you're writing unit test, right?) you want to isolate your system under test (NavigationDecorator) from its dependencies (controller). You can write this test:

```
describe NavigationDecorator do 
  context 'user_id'
    it 'should take id from session' do 
      session = { temporary_id: 'temporary' } 
      controller = instance_double('ApplicationController', session: session)
      user = instance_double('User', id: 'user_id')
      subject = described_class.new(user, session)
      expect(subject.retrieve_user_id).to eq session[:temporary_id]
    end  
  end
end
```

The test shows us that we have unneeded dependency (controller) and it would be cleaner to pass session right away (if you can, of course):

```
describe NavigationDecorator do 
  context 'user_id'
    it 'should take id from session' do 
      session = { temporary_id: 'temporary' } 
      subject = described_class.new('local id', session)
      expect(subject.retrieve_user_id).to eq session[:temporary_id]
    end  

    it 'should take id from user when session is empty' do 
      controller = instance_double('ApplicationController', session: {})
      user = instance_double('User', id: 'user_id')
      subject = described_class.new(user, session)
      expect(subject.retrieve_user_id).to eq user.id
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! With your answer I was able to solve my problem. Just one quick question. In case my decorator also SETS a sesion variable, how could I accomplish this without having to re-setting the session and re-creating the decorator?

Comment: Could you write an example, I don't fully understand why do you need to reset the session?